# Integrate airbrake with Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, airbrake

When I'm trying to integrate python logging with airbrake, I get following errors:

```
main.py

import pybrake
from config2.config import config

airbrake_handler = None

def filter_airbrake_msgs(notice):
    if config.environment in ['production', 'staging']:
        return notice
    return None


def config_airbrake():
    print(config.py_brake)

    notifier = pybrake.Notifier(
        project_id=config.py_brake.project_id,
        project_key=config.py_brake.project_key
    )

config_airbrake()
```

ENV=development python3 main.py

```
Error :

ERROR pybrake get_git_revision failed: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/user/xxx/xxx/xxx/.git/HEAD'
```

Comment: that happened when you ran the program?

Comment: yes, it happened when I ran the program.

Comment: See @vladimir-mihailenco answer but you can check the exit code of your previous command. `echo $?` which should indicate this is innocuous.

Answer (score 1):

That looks like a log message coming from https://github.com/airbrake/pybrake/blob/master/pybrake/git.py#L12. I see why it is confusing but it is actually harmless and you can ignore it. I've created an [issue](https://github.com/airbrake/pybrake/issues/34) to remove that log message. And feel free to use Github issues for such questions in future.

Overall pybrake checks if directory stored in `context.rootDirectory` contains a Git folder. If there is a git folder there it tries to extract some info like git revision, checkout date etc. Otherwise it logs the first error.